# Cannot call value of non-function type

Tags: append, swift5

I'm trying to build a simulation of an art education game which essentially has a deck of 86 cards each with 4 icons representing a data period, a region and two icons for picture type.  To start with, I'm trying to write the code to build the deck of cards by defining a card as a 'struct' after enumerating the icon types and then create a deck of these cards as an array.  I've looked at similar code for building a normal 52 playing card decking and tried to reuse the ideas but I'm hitting a problem when trying to append a card to the deck.  The key bit of code is:

```
enum DateGroup{
    
    case DG1, DG2, DG3
    
    static let allValues = [DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG1,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG2,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3, DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3,    DG3]
    
}

enum CountryGroup: String {
    
    case IT, NE, FS, US
    
    static let allValues = [IT,    IT,    IT,    IT,    IT,    IT,    IT,    IT,    NE,     NE,     IT,    NE,     NE,     NE,     IT,    IT,    IT,    NE,     IT,    NE,     IT,    IT,    IT,    NE,     IT,    IT,    IT,    IT,    NE,     IT,    NE,     NE,     FS,    FS,    NE,     IT,    IT,    NE,     NE,     IT,    IT,    NE,     FS,    FS,    FS,    NE,     FS,    NE,     NE,     NE,     NE,     FS,    NE,     NE,     FS,    NE,     IT,    NE,     NE,     FS,    FS,    NE,     IT,    NE,     FS,    NE,     NE,     NE,     NE,     FS,    FS,    FS,    FS,    FS,    US,    FS,    FS,    FS,    FS,    NE,     FS,    FS,    FS,    NE,     US,    IT]
    
}

enum IconGroup: String {
    
    case Portrait, People, Still, Scape, Setting
    
    static let allValues1 = [Portrait,     People,    People,    Portrait,     Portrait,     People,    People,    People,    People,    Portrait,     People,    Portrait,     People,    People,    People,    Portrait,     People,    Portrait,     People,    Portrait,     Portrait,     People,    People,    Portrait,     People,    People,    Portrait,     People,    Portrait,     People,    Portrait,     People,    Portrait,     People,    People,    People,    People,    Still,    People,    Portrait,     People,    Portrait,     Still,    People,    People,    People,    Portrait,     Still,    People,    Portrait,     Portrait,     People,    Still,    Still,    People,    Still,    People,    Portrait,     Portrait,     People,    People,    People,    People,    Portrait,     Portrait,     People,    Scape,    Scape,    Setting,    People,    People,    Still,    People,    Still,    Setting,    Scape,    People,    People,    People,    Still,    Still,    Portrait,     People,    Portrait,     People,    People]
    
    static let allValues2 = [Setting,    Setting,    Setting,    Setting,    Setting,    Setting,    Setting,    Scape,    Setting,    Setting,    Scape,    Scape,    Setting,    Setting,    Scape,    Scape,    Setting,    Scape,    Setting,    Scape,    Scape,    Scape,    Scape,    Setting,    Scape,    Scape,    Setting,    Scape,    Setting,    Setting,    Portrait,     Setting,    Setting,    Setting,    Scape,    Portrait,     Setting,    Still,    Scape,    Setting,    Scape,    Setting,    Still,    Scape,    Scape,    Scape,    Setting,    Still,    Scape,    Portrait,     Setting,    Setting,    Still,    Still,    Scape,    Still,    Scape,    Portrait,     Scape,    Setting,    Scape,    Setting,    Scape,    Setting,    Setting,    Scape,    Scape,    Scape,    Scape,    Scape,    Scape,    Still,    Scape,    Still,    Still,    Scape,    Setting,    Setting,    Scape,    Still,    Still,    Setting,    Setting,    Setting,    Setting,    Setting]
    
}


struct Card {
    
    var dateGroup: DateGroup
    var countryGroup: CountryGroup
    var icon1: IconGroup
    var icon2: IconGroup
    
    init(dateGroup: DateGroup, countryGroup: CountryGroup, icon1: IconGroup, icon2: IconGroup) {
        
        self.dateGroup = dateGroup
        self.countryGroup = countryGroup
        self.icon1 = icon1
        self.icon2 = icon2       
    }
}


class DeckOfCard {

    //raw data for deck of cards

    var deckOfCards: [Card]
    
    var deckSize = DateGroup.allValues.count
    
    //Create deck of cards from the arrays
    
    init (){
        
        self.deckOfCards = [Card]()
        
        for index in 0..<deckSize {                
            self.deckOfCards.append(Card(dateGroup: <#T##DateGroup#>, countryGroup: <#T##CountryGroup#>, icon1: <#T##IconGroup#>, icon2: <#T##IconGroup#>))
            
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I  try to enter the value from an array in the append statement e.g.

self.deckOfCards.append(Card(dateGroup: DateGroup.allValues(index), countryGroup: <#T##CountryGroup#>, icon1: <#T##IconGroup#>, icon2: <#T##IconGroup#>))

I thought that would pick up an item from the array 'allValues' defined under the enum for DateGroup but I get an error of the type "Cannot call value of non-function type '[DateGroup]'"

I'm still a newbie with the Swift coding so any help much appreciated!!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to subscribe an array by index are square brackets rather than parentheses:

```
  self.deckOfCards.append(Card(dateGroup: DateGroup.allValues[index], 
                            countryGroup: CountryGroup.allValues[index], 
                                   icon1: IconGroup.allValues1[index], 
                                   icon2: IconGroup.allValues2[index]))
```

Please read [Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) in the Swift Language Guide

Comment: Awesome!  Can't believe I made such a newbie error - doh!  Thanks so much.